# How to setup web.config to use SmtpClient

Tags: c#, azure, razor, smtp, web-config

I'm not even sure how to word the question, but here is what I am trying to do. I have a PHP website hosted on Azure with one CSHTML page found below that is a simple contact form. Once I try adding

```
    System.Web.Mail.SmtpClient client = new  System.Web.Mail.SmtpClient();
```

I get the most unhelpful runtime error of "An application error occurred on the server." and nothing else to help me. What do I need to include for this to work? I tried making a web.config file like :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mail" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

and then I grabbed all my DLL files from another project and created a Bin folder in the wwwroot directory and put them in there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Contact form that works until I add the SmtpClient:

```
@using System.Web;
@using System.Web.Mail;
@{ 
<title>Contact Me</title> 

var fName = HttpContext.Current.Request["fName"];
var lName = HttpContext.Current.Request["lName"];
var eMail = HttpContext.Current.Request["eMail"];
var qComment = HttpContext.Current.Request["qComment"];
var Submit = HttpContext.Current.Request["Submit"];
}

@if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST")
{ 
<h1>You are POST</h1>
 System.Web.Mail.SmtpClient client = new  System.Web.Mail.SmtpClient();
} 


<h2>Have a question? Feel free to contact me:</h2>

<div id="contactForm">
<form method="post">  

<p>First Name:</p> 
<p><input type="text" name="fName" value="@fName" /></p>

<p>Last Name:</p> 
<p><input type="text" name="lName" value="@lName" /></p>

<p>E-mail:</p> 
<p><input type="email" name="eMail" value="@eMail" /></p>

<p>Question/Comment:</p> 
<p><textarea name="qComment" rows="10" cols="20">@qComment</textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></p> 
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: PHP webapp with cshtml page ! how does that happen

Comment: Here is for webmatrix: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_php.asp  . Anyway, I just said screw it and created a new website project in Visual Studio and added my entire website just to make that one darn page. If anyone is curios why I did this its because I have a student subscription to Azure and I am not able to use sendgrid :( and I wasn't having much luck figuring out how to modify php.ini in Azure.

Comment: in azure webapps you can add a .user.ini file to your root directory and give your webapp a restart, that .user.ini is considered your php.ini file.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of crossing two different languages I found Swiftmailer for php and I used that.